# Why is =+ (equals plus) valid in Apex?

Tags: apex

Just fixed an unfortunate bug. I was trying to concatenate a string. But it kept getting replaced by the string it should have been adding. Couldn't figure it out for a while.

I was doing the operation like this:

```
attendeesListFormatted =+ attendeeFormated;
```

Took me a while to see my dyslexic mistake. Then I wondered why is that valid? Wouldn't it encounter an unexpected character after the assignment?

Then it occurred to me that maybe Apex was treating it as a null concatenation. Like so:

```
attendeesListFormatted = '' + attendeeFormated;
```

Can anyone think of another reason my mistake wouldn't thrown an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is exactly what it is:

```
Integer i;
i += 1;
```

This give dereference null object error

```
i =+ 1;
```

I is now equal to one.

I cannot find this documented in the Salesforce Operators documentation though.

Comment: It makes sense if you read it like `i = +1`

Answer (score 7):

As Lex commented, what you have with `i =+ 1` is the *Assignment operator (Right associative)* and the positive equivalent of the *Unary negation operator* : the Unary Plus Operator.

It does seem odd that you can use a unary operator on a string, were the `+` is otherwise used for concatenation with two operands. Typically the Unary Plus Operator requires a numeric operand. In this case I'd expect an Integer or Double.

See [Understanding Expression Operators](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)